# Angular 2 fill variable with return JSON info from HTTP Request

Tags: json, angular

I'm pretty new on Angular2, and I'm trying to obtain the key/value pair from a JSON file returned by a Http request. I want to store them on the objectResource property so I can retrieve them on the template.

This is my **component.ts**:

```
export class ResourceDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    objectResource: any = Array();
    id:any;
    sub:any;

    constructor(private contentService: ContentService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            this.id = +params['id'];
        });

        this.getResource(this.id);
     }

    ngOnInit(){}

    private getResource(id:number) {
        return this.contentService.getSpecificResource(id).then(res => this.objectResource.push(res));
    }


}
```

and this is mi **service.ts:**

```
public getSpecificResource(id:number) {
        return this.http.get(`http://resources.dev/v1/resources/show/${id}`)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json());
    }
```

when I do `console.log` on res I obtain this log, which mean the service is doing the request as expected:

```
Object {
    id: 1, 
    name: "quisquam", 
    image: "http://lorempixel.com/480/480/?88330", 
    description: "Consequuntur quo provident alias aut rerum.", 
    author: "Marc Mann Sr."
}
```

I've tried to retrieve these values on the template using `{{objectResource.name}}` but isn't working, and I don't know how can I access this values from the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `subscribe` which will auto update the object when value is resolved.

**component.ts**

```
private getResource(id:number) {
    return this.contentService.getSpecificResource(id)
        .subscribe(res => this.objectResource = res,
                   err => console.log(err));
```

**template.html**

```
 <div *ngIf='objectResource'>
    {{objectResource.name}}
 </div>
```

**OR**

Use `async` pipe that can receive a Promise or Observable as input and subscribe to the input automatically, eventually returning the emitted value(s).

**component.ts**

```
private getResource(id:number) {
   this.objectResource = this.contentService.getSpecificResource(id);
   return this.objectResource;
}
```

**template.html**

```
 <div *ngIf='objectResource | async'>
    {{objectResource.name}}
 </div>
```

Comment: How can I use .subscribe? when I tried to add it it says subscribe property doesn't exist on type 'Promise<any>

Comment: sure, there it is.

Comment: I finally solved it by using your subscribe idea, had to change mi service so instead of `.toPromise()` I've used `.map()` and then subscribe worked as expected. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

objectResource is an array not an object. Just do it like

```
{{objectResource[0].name}}
```

Please consider add checking before printing it because angular will throw an error if the array is undefined

Answer (score 0):

When the template is loaded, the objectResource might not be ready. Try to put ? from your objectResource like this

```
 {{objectResource?.name}}
```

or insert a div element like this

```
  <div *ngIf='objectResource'>
    {{objectResource.name}}
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's change detection is not triggered when an object is mutated (e.g. an element is added to your array).  See [Triggering Angular2 change detection manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually).  Specifically this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/42695581/3103979

Answer (score 0):

First of all make this change

```
export class ResourceDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    objectResource: Array<any> = [];
    ..........
}
```

If there will be an array of multiple data.

```
<div *ngFor='let data of objectResource'>
    <div> id : {{data.id}} </div>
    <div> name : {{data.name}} </div>
    <div> description : {{data.description}} </div>
    .....
</div>
```

This will show data if there is any data inside "`objectResource`"